# Why does my hot cooktop indicator light stay on too long?

Tags: stove

Why does my hot cooktop indicator light stay on after the cooktop is cool?  The indicator light never turns off.

Comment: It *never* turns off, or it just takes a while?

Comment: What make and model? How are you measuring "cool" by hand or with a thermometer?

Comment: This will happen sometimes to my 15 year old Amana glass top range. I put a tray, large pan on top of the glass stop and add a layer of ice cubes. Watch that the melting ice don't overflow the pan or tray. The light went off. I did this a week ago and the light has not got stuck again.

Answer (score 3):

This indicator may be driven by some form of [temperature sensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_temperature_sensors).  If the light is staying on too long; or indefinitely, there is likely something wrong with the sensor, the sensor wiring, or the control board that interprets the signal from the sensor.

Without knowing the make and model of the stove, it's impossible to tell you where the sensor is, what type it is, how exactly to troubleshoot it, how to replace it, or if it can be adjusted.

The basic idea is that when the stove top heats up, the temperature sensor sends a signal either directly to the light, or to a control board. This causes the light to come on, and stay on as long as the stove top is above a certain temperature.  When the stove top cools down, the signal is no longer sent, and the light goes out.

Comment: Is it possible the stovetop just has a simple timer that keeps the warning light on for 30 minutes or so?

Comment: @Tester101 - Is it also possible or probable that the temperature light is designed to stay on for a long time as a safety measure? Would these sensors measure the absolute temperature or would they measure the temperature relative to some room-temperature component of the stove?

Comment: @Freiheit I would think absolute temperature.